# React Chakra ui Button call function while pressed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I trying to make the button from chakra ui continue calling the callback while the user press the button, but no success in a sollution yet

anyone already do that or it only can be made in a react native?

```
<Button onClick={() => handleChangeValue(100, "sub")}>Decrement</Button>
```

So, while the user keep the button press, the callback will continuously call and decrement the value

Comment: could you share example source code? I try like your button, I ddin't see any problem. [here ] (https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-dew-4cvvw5?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: it's not a problem, it's like a new feature, i need to keep calling the funcition while user keep pressing the button, like in a smartphone when we not take our finger from the button